# Cookie Not Saved for Treasure Hunt Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

first time poster, long time reader.

So I needed to create a quick and simple treasure hunt. The ideas was to store some values in a cookie and, when the user click on an element with a matching id, update the following value. It's not in there yet but when the person has found all 8 (in this case) it will trigger something.

Now, I've gotten it to mostly work but I'm running in to a big problem. The cookie is not being stored from page to page. If I'm working off a single test page it's just fine - the cookie is created, values are pulled from it and put in to a check array, and the counter increments correctly. Also, when the cookie is updated the new values are being stored just fine.

However, when I go to another page and check for the cookie - it's gone. Now I checked to see if the cookie was actually getting dropped in and yes, it's there. But there are multiple cookies all with the same name (they are updating values - but again it's only page to page so no cumulative effect).

So, I guess I don't understand why when I call the cookie and reset it, it's not affecting a single cookie but creating a new one?

Oh, I'm using jQuery 1.4.2 and the jQuery cookie plugin.

```
// if not present create default array and store in cookie cookie
if($.cookie('treasure_hunt') == null) {

var treasure = new Array(
    "arteContactEn",0,
    "arteCorpEn",0,
    "arteServicesEn",0,
    "arteRoomsEn",0,
    "arteDiningEn",0,
    "artePackEn",0,
    "arteHotelEn",0,
    "arteHomeEn", 0
)
   $.cookie('treasure_hunt', treasure, { expires: 7 });
}

// capture cookie info
var treasureFound = $.cookie('treasure_hunt');

// create check array and parse values into it
var treasureCheck = new Array();
var treasureCheck = treasureFound.split(',');

// function checks array and tallies total found items
function checkFound() { 
var foundItems = 0;

for(var i=0; i<treasureCheck.length; i++) {
    var value = treasureCheck[i];
    if(value == 1) {
        ++foundItems;
    }
}
// writes found items to span on page
$('.thProgress').text(foundItems);

}

// check number artefacts and write to page
var treasureTotal = treasureCheck.length / 2;
$('.thTotal').text(treasureTotal);

// on click checks element id against array and, if found, marks the following value as 1
$('.artefact-right, .artefact-left').click(function(){
var artefactID = $(this).attr('id');

for(var e=0; e<treasureCheck.length; e++) {
    var matchID = treasureCheck[e];
    var k = e + 1;

    if(matchID == artefactID) {
        treasureCheck[k] = 1;

        // checks for total found items
        checkFound();

        // updates cookie with new array
        $.cookie('treasure_hunt', treasureCheck, { expires: 7 });
    }

}

});
```

Comment: Are all pages in the same domain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [README file in github](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/README.rdoc), you need to define the path the cookie is valid for if you don't want it to be only for the page it was created on:

> Define the path where cookie is valid. **By default the path of the
>   cookie is the path of the page where the cookie was created (standard
>   browser behavior).** If you want to make it available for instance
>   across the entire page use path: '/'. If you want to delete a cookie
>   with a particular path, you need to include that path in the call.

So I think it would be something like this:

```
$.cookie('treasure_hunt', treasure, { expires: 7, path: '/' });
```

P.S. You're missing a semicolon at the end of your `var treasure = new Array()` declaration.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me so quick! That was pretty amazing - I went to grab a bowl of soup then BAM! problem solved.